# 2D Array Concatenation

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need a method that given input 2D array {{1,2},{3,4}} and (int)row=2; (int)column = 3, will produce a concatenated 2D array {{1,2,1,2,1,2}{3,4,3,4,3,4}}.

My attempt was to use a nested for loop to expand them both horizontally and and vertically, but was unsuccessful. This is what I have so far:

```
    int row = 2;
    int column = 5;
    int count = 0;
    int[][] list = {{12,3},{3,4}};

    int [][] renewed = new int[row*list.length][column*list[0].length]; 

    for (int l = 0; l<list.length; l++) {
        for (int k = 0; k<renewed.length; k+= list.length) {
            renewed[l+k] = list[l];
        }
    }        

    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(renewed));       
    }
}
```

^This produces list[][] expanded vertically, for the first column

```
    int row = 2;
    int column = 4;
    int[][] list = {{12,3},{3,4}};

    int [][] renewed = new int[row*list.length][column*list[0].length]; 
    for (int i = 0; i<list[0].length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<renewed[0].length; j+=list[0].length) {
            renewed[0][j+i] = list[0][i];
        }
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(renewed[0]));       
}
```

^This produces list[][] expanded horizontally, for the first row;

So how can I concatenate these two methods in order to produce a method that expands BOTH **horizontally and vertically**?

Comment: How would input 3 produce an array of size 5 ?

Comment: I am just testing out with different values. You can ignore specific values that I used, as I am looking for a general answer, not one tailored to this specific array.

Comment: but this does not help in solving the problem actually. How do you want your original array being modified exactly?

Comment: I am converting a jpg image to a 2D array, then making a "tile" method to create multiples of that array. So that I can convert it back to image and get multiple images of the same picture.

Comment: much clearer. Thank you

Comment: If user inputs 3 for row and 5 for column, my image would be 3x5 of that image with 15 individual images glued together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to iterate over every position in the new array and use the remainder operator `%` to get the right entry of the original.

```
int[][] list = {{1,2},{3,4}};
int row = 2;
int column = 5;
int [][] renewed = new int[row*list.length][column*list[0].length];
for (int i = 0; i < renewed.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < renewed[0].length; j++) {
        renewed[i][j] = list[i % list.length][j % list[0].length];
    }
}
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(renewed));
```

Comment: @mathlover No problem. Glad I could help.